# Homotopy type of a $4$-manifold with finite fundamental group (paper by S. Bauer)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, 4-manifolds

I'm studying Stefan Bauer's paper

> *The homotopy type of a 4-manifold with finite fundamental group*. In: tom Dieck T. (eds) Algebraic Topology and Transformation Groups. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 1361. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, doi:[10.1007/BFb0083030](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0083030).

unfortunately not for free, for most universities accessible) and have a question about the proof of Proposition 1 or more precisely the construction of a commutative diagram used in the proof.

Let $X$ be an oriented $4$-dimensional Poincaré complex with finite fundamental group $G$ and $f: X \to B$ its $2$-stage Postinokov approximation. let $\gamma(X)$ denote the intersection form on $H_2(\tilde{X})$; we denote by $\tilde{X}$ the universal cover of $X$. Then $S_4^{PD}(B, \gamma(X))$ denotes the set of homotopy types of $4$-dimensional Poincaré complexes $Y$, together with $3$-equivalences $g:Y \to B$, such that $f$ and $g$ induce isometry of the quadratic $2$-types. [...]

The statement of **Proposition 1** is:

> If $X$ is a Poincaré space with finite fundamental group $G$, then there is a bijection $\hat{H_0}(G;\pi_3(X)) \to S_4^{PD}(B, \gamma(X))$.

In the proof the following commutative diagram is imposed:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>  >> 0 @>  >> 0 @> >> 0 @> >> 0\\
@VVV  @VVV  @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>  >> H_4(\bar{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{ZG}} \mathbb{Z} @>  >> H_4(\bar{B}) \otimes_{\mathbb{ZG}} \mathbb{Z} @> >> H_4(\bar{B},\bar{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{ZG}} \mathbb{Z} @> >> 0\\
@VVV  @VVV  @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>  >> H_4(X) @>  >> H_4(B) @> >> H_4(B,X) @> >> 0\\
@VVV  @VVV  @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>  >> H_4(X, \bar{X}) @>  >> H_4(B, \bar{B}) @> >> 0 @> >> 0\\
@VVV  @VVV  @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>  >> 0 @>  >> 0 @> >> 0 @> >> 0
\end{CD}
$$

as David Roberts correctly pointed out, this diagram was in the excerpt called "pushout diagram"

The **Question** is simply that I not understand how this diagram arises.

The horizontal sequences seem to come from homological exact 
sequence of pairs $(X,B)$ respectively $(\bar{X},\bar{B})$. the $H_5(-)$ 
of the left side vanish by dimensional reasons, since our manifold has dimension 
$4$. Why vanish $H_3(\bar{B},\bar{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{ZG}} \mathbb{Z}$ and 
$H_3(B,X)$ on the right side?

Additionally, which construction gives rise to vertical sequences? It looks like 
some version of the [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem). But this one I do not fully understand.

addendum: as David Roberts correctly pointed out, this diagram was in the excerpt called "pushout diagram". I still not know why it is called "pushout diagram", but I'm pretty sure, that the answer to this question would also provide an answer of my primary question.

Comment: The diagram is described as a "pushout diagram", but it's not quite clear where the pushout is happening in the diagram.

Comment: yes, thank you for this remark, I will update this aspect. possibly, it's a good starting point to find the answer.

Comment: On the left you have $H_5$, not $H_3$.

Comment: yes, you are right, I thought too cohomological :) I fix it